# Tag clouds similar to mirror.me using php and/or jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, tag-cloud

Have a look a http://mirror.me/fzmvdr8e

I believe this is java code on the serverside. Are there any similar solutions using php and/or jquery? Thanks

Comment: No it is just PHP and CSS. Look at this: http://s3.amazonaws.com/tagcloudimage/00/02/42/51/0002425151_sprite.png?v=17.32850829841587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page http://mirror.me/fzmvdr8e is made with HTML5, CSS3, PHP, and JavaScript only. View the source code to check it out for yourself. Follow what they have set up there, and try some of the features of the page out yourself. Good luck!